# Test for audio with no speakers

Tags: c#, audio-player

I am currently debugging some code in C# which plays a noise (in this case a beep) under certain conditions.

The computer I am using has no speakers or working headphone jack, is there any way in which I can detect sound being played without actually being able to hear it?

The code that plays the sound is:

```
else System.Media.SystemSounds.Exclamation.Play();
```

Comment: Other than checking that your code actually reaches the method that plays your sound, I don't think so. Shouldn't that be enough?

Comment: @henrikmerlander The issue is not reaching the code, it definitely does, but I am not 100% sure that the sound actually plays, I will edit to add the code

Comment: On which windows are you?

Comment: @Thomas I am using Windows 7

Comment: Does the [windows audio mixer](http://www.windows7hacker.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/image20.png) fit your need?

Comment: you can always have [virtual audio drive](http://superuser.com/questions/117625/how-to-create-a-virtual-audio-device-and-stream-audio-input-with-it) to capture your sound output without actually playing them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have any device in the device manager, you can install a [Realtek Driver](https://www.realtek.com/en/downloads). It creates a virtual playback device.

After that, go to sound-playing devices, choose the virtual device and set it as default playback device. Open your app and check whether a sound is played by looking at the volume visualisation next to the device in the device manager.

[image]
<sub>(source: [eightforums.com](https://www.eightforums.com/attachments/sound-audio/39269d1394311636t-lg-tv-not-playing-sound-when-connected-via-hdmi-cable-capture.png))</sub>

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me, I will accept this answer once that is an available option. Also, nice picture.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows, I believe (provided the audio drivers are loaded, and Windows thinks there's at least some form of audio output device) - you can open the volume setting (from the system tray) and see the bar bounce up and down when sound is being generated.

Alternatively, if the box is running Windows Professional, RDP to it from a remote device?  The audio will be passed over the RDP session and played on the client.

Answer (score 1):

Search "Sound" in Windows (Control Panel), it shows you all your devices with the volume it outputs to that device.
You can see if your sound works by looking the current volume (the bar on the right of each device).

[image: Sound panel (Win 7)]

If your PC has no audio out device (I don'think it's the case), maybe you can add "virtual" output devices.

Comment: This would work in most situations, but my computer has no audio driver whatsoever, so in this case Kazarp's answer is more suited, but this is still correct for someone else who may face the same issue!

Comment: Well, it's exactly the same suggestion... he just sent it while I was typing mine. :)